# Set aspect ratio of JCrop on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I am using JCrop to allow users to crop images when uploading them.

There are two possible image crop sizes that are allowed, for example 16:10 or 4:3.

I would like to be able to add two input buttons, and have one of them set the aspect ratio as 16:10, and the other 4:3.

This is the code to set the aspect to 16:10 with the page load, Is it possible to have it change to 4:3 on button press?

```
<script language="Javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#crop').Jcrop({
            aspectRatio: 16 / 10
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it like that :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var jcrop_api;
    $('#crop').Jcrop({
        aspectRatio: 16 / 10
    }, function () {
        jcrop_api = this;    
    });
});
```

then on the click event :

```
jcrop_api.setOptions({ aspectRatio: 4 / 3 });
jcrop_api.focus();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I am getting this error on the console however. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jcrop_api is not defined`

Comment: I had missed out the `var jcrop_api;` Although getting new error for `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setOptions' of undefined`